# what for it's working additive-symbols at CSS3?

Tags: css

I am see this documentation at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style/additive-symbols

but I don't  understand true,  what for it's working

down is code example :

HTML5

```html
<ul class="list">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

CSS3

```css
@counter-style additive-symbols-example {
  system: additive;
  additive-symbols: I 1;
}
.list {
  list-style: additive-symbols-example;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS isn't a *replacement* for the HTML; it's supplementary (you need both).

Including the relevant HTML with your CSS shows that it does indeed work as intended:

```css
@counter-style additive-symbols-example {
  system: additive;
  additive-symbols: I 1;
}

.list {
  list-style: additive-symbols-example;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

**However**, note that at the moment, additive symbols are **[only supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style/additive-symbols#Browser_compatibility)** (from Firefox 33 and onwards). In Firefox, this produces:

[image: Symbols]

In all other browsers you will only see the regular bullet points rendered.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Excellent answer :)

Comment: Glad to hear you think that. If it's an excellent answer, you could always consider [**marking it as correct**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) or [**upvoting it**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)